# How to set Max on input text using angular JS

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-mvc-3

I want to set max value for an amount field using angular JS

If i enter value > 10 i want to display an error message next to the textbox. Since type="text" it is not working like number.

```
<input type="text" name="input" ng-model="example.value"   ngmin="0" ngmax="10" >
```

Comment: Why don't make it type `type="number"`?

Comment: Why don't you use type="number"?

Comment: and then use `ng-if` to display a message when `example.value` is `null`

Comment: i want to show the one i am typing in text box even if it is characters. type="number" restricts me for entering characters

Comment: You mean default value?

Comment: You mean user can't enter to input a number greater than 10 ?

Comment: Please clarify what logic you expecting. E.g. `"a text" > 10 = ?`, `"9" > 10 = ?`, `"a10" > 10 = ?`

Answer (score 0):

As they said before would be better that you just change the type to "number". But you can do it anyways with input wiht a function in the controller parsing the number like this:

```
.controller('myCtrl', function ($scope) {

  $scope.parse = function(i){
    return  parseInt(i);
  }
});
```

And in the html using a ng-if:

```
<input type="text" ng-model="myNum">
<p class="bad-input" ng-if="parse(myNum)>10 ||parse(myNum)<0 ">The number is wrong</p>
```

Here is a working [Plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/XUrIlcP1fIIB2UK3vR22?p=preview)

Comment: I tried this . it worked . I would like to highlight the text box on error . For required check (mandatory check ) i use data-ng-class="{'has-error':amount.$invalid}"  which will highlihjt to red. can i get this error also highlighed

Comment: i have a save button which will get disabled if there is an error . but if i add the above validation it is not gettign disabled

Comment: You could use the same expression to the ng-class directive, and the same expresion (negated) to hide or disable the button. I updated the Plunker so you can check it, but as was said should be better and easier use the type="number" input.

Comment: I wanted to show the button but in disabled mode. So what i did is modified this as : $scope.parse = function(i){ myform.$invalid=true
      return  parseInt(i); . But here the button is not getting disabled. I have done some mistake i think . here is the disabled portion of my button  data-ng-disabled="EditLocksandlimitsform.$invalid"  .Highlighting error is working as you updated.

Comment: i do have other validations on the same field like required and ng-pattern

Comment: Its the same for disabled. I updated again the Plunker. I recomend you to check documentation and tutorials about forms and form validation like [this docs](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/forms) or [this tutorial](https://scotch.io/tutorials/angularjs-form-validation)

Comment: As you mentioned i have added || condition to check amount> 10 and it is working . In my example i tried setting $invalid from my js file and it is not working. Do you have any idea on it.   https://plnkr.co/edit/eec21SGdNUx7B4hfIW0W?p=preview

Comment: using System;
     
public class Program
{
 public static void Main()
    {
  string a1 = @"AU\abcdef";
       a1 = a1.Replace("\\", "\\\");
     
  Console.WriteLine(a1);
  
    }
}this is working . But if i change a1 = "AU\abcdef"; (without @) it is not working. any urgent help please